# Android App Widget button click not working properly

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am making a simple app widget that displays a toast message when a button in the widget is touched.  The issue I am having is that the toast never appears when the button is clicked.  In fact, the onReceive event is never fired when the button is touched.  I suspect the issue has to do with my manifest, but it looks ok to me.

Here is the relevant portions of my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".GPSWidget" android:label="GPS Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="luke.app.steal.GPSWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
</receiver>
```

Here is the code to "wire up" the button to an event listener, as well as the onReceive event it is in a class called GPSReceiver.

```
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
{
        RemoteViews remoteViews;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.gpswidget );
        remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widgetTexts, "Click Me!");

        Intent inte = new Intent(context, lukeService.class);
        inte.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);

        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, inte, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetTexts, configPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews );
}
```

widgetTexts is the button that should be launching the toast, but like I said nothing happens when the button is hit.  I thought that my path in the manifest was wrong, luke.app.steal, but that same path works just fine for all my other activities.

Anyone got any ideas? or need more info?

Comment: try not to use onRecieve() widgetprovider takes care of.

Comment: In `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, inte, 0)`, try changing the value of the request code(0) to something else, which is not used by any other pending intent in your app.

Comment: @faizal You just saved me a lot of frustration!  Thank you so much.  Widgets in Android are the worst to make and debug.